# Integration of a recursive function

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following equation (where $\alpha$ is a constant and $t \in \mathbb R$):
$$f_k'=\alpha f_{k-1}(t)$$
whose solution has to be:
$$f_k(t)=\frac{(\alpha t)^k}{k!}$$
But how?

Comment: You will need an $f_0$ or something to start with.  But then try proof by induction.

Comment: The problem is incomplete. As said above you would need an initial function like $f_0$, but you also need a condition for each $k$ like $f_k(0) = 0$. I suspect that the full problem reads $f_k' = \alpha f_{k-1}$ with $f_k(0) = 0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f_0(x) = 1$. Then induction does the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately no other data were given...I just could _suppose_ that $f_k(0)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.  Let's start with $f_0$ and assume that the initial condition is $0$ (i.e. $f_0(0) = 0$).  We know that $(f_1)'(t) = \alpha f_0$.

Then, $f_1(t) = \alpha t f_0$.  Next, we know that $(f_2)'(t) = \alpha f_1(t) = \alpha ^2 tf_0$.  Integrating, we find that
$f_2(t) = \frac{1}{2} \alpha^2 t^2 = \frac{1}{2} (\alpha t)^2$.  Can you finish the problem from here?

Comment: Excuse me if I ask you one more thing: why integrating $f_2'$ gives $a^2t^2/2$ and not $a^2t^2f_0/2$?

Comment: Ohh, sorry.  I didn't see that.  I guess you just have to also assume that $f_0 = 1$.

Comment: To be strickt here the integral of $f_1' = \alpha$ is not $f_1 = \alpha t$ but $\alpha t + C$. There is an integration constant at every integration step we need to fix. You have implicitly assumed $f_k(0) = 0$ (which is what one needs to do to get what OP has)